# Color inside a box in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to fill with light blue in the box.

```
\node   at (0,-1.25) {\boxed{$+$}};
```

If I use

```
\node[fill=blue!20]   at (0,-1.25) {\boxed{$+$}};
```

color comes outside also.

Please help me.

Comment: Why don't you just use the `draw` option for your node?

Comment: Please provide MWE, which reproduce your problem. See if `empheq` package can help you.

Comment: Actually, the `\boxed` command only adds a box around your plus sign, but your node is wider than this sign, so it's entirely coloured (and also outside the box). You need to play with `inner sep` and use the `draw` argument for your node. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in my comment, here's your problem and a posible solution:

[image: boxed]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node {\boxed{$+$}};
        \node[fill=blue!20]   at (0,-1) {\boxed{$+$}};
        \node[draw,inner sep=4pt,fill=blue!20] at (0,-2) {$+$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As I understand the question, OP like to have only colored content of `boxed`, not whole node. But I may be wrong.

Comment: That's why I presented an option by colouring the node, just in case. By the way, `\boxed` is now overtaken by what `hf-tikz` package offers. I'll go for it if I were OP and needed more complex colouring of boxes.